# Ansible, set_fact using if then else statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am trying to set a variable in Ansible with set_fact at runtime based upon another variable. If uses first value no matter what the actual value is. Here is my code example:

```
- name: Global_vars - get date info
    set_fact:  
      jm_env: "{{lookup('env', 'Environment')}}"
      l_env: "{% if '{{jm_env}}==Develop' %}d{% elif '{{jm_env}}==Staging'%}s{% else %}p{% endif %}"
```

`l_env` is `d` no matter what `jm_env` is set.

Answer (score 21):

Firstly, dictionaries in YAML are not ordered (and the syntax used by Ansible here is a YAML dictionary), so you have no guarantee Ansible would first set `jm_env` before proceeding to `l_env` -- you need to split the assignment into two tasks.

Secondly, your test expressions are incorrect -- `'{{jm_env}}==Develop'` is a string because it is quoted; and testing `if 'string'` will always evaluate to `true` (this is the direct reason you always get `d` in the output).

Use:

```
- name: Set the jm_env
    set_fact:  
      jm_env: "{{lookup('env', 'Environment')}}"

- name: Set the l_env
    set_fact:  
      l_env: "{% if jm_env=='Develop' %}d{% elif jm_env=='Staging'%}s{% else %}p{% endif %}"
```

Comment: that worked. i didn't realize the order could be the issue

Comment: @thepod71 Please have a look at the Help Center: [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 11):

One of the simple way to set fact based condition example as follows:

```
  - name: Set facts for delete operation results
    set_fact:
        tr_result: "{{ '{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\"}' if (op_result['output'] == 'Deleted') else '{\"status\" : \"FAILED\"}' }}"
```

Note: Assume **op_result** is a dict & already defined.

Code has been tested and working well.