# Ansible - Conditionnally change an option value

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task that ensures that a list (`dict`) of users is created and create them if needed.

I want that this task don't update the passwords (only `on_creation`) except when I set a global variable `enforce_config` to `true`. In that case i want to all managed users get there password updated with the default one (stored in my users dict).

In a short I want based on the value of `enforce_config` variable change this `user` module option:

```
update_password: on_create
```

into:

```
update_password: always
```

Here is the complete task:

```yaml
  - name: Manage users and their password
  user:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    home: "{{ item.value.home }}"
    createhome: yes
    shell: "{{ item.value.shell }}"
    password: "{{ item.value.password }}"
  # IF `enforce_config` == true
  #   update_password: always
  # ELSE
    update_password: on_create
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935820/ansible-set-fact-using-if-then-else-statement), I actually found an answer to my own question.

- Directly with a Jinja2 if-else in the `update_password` option of the task:

`update_password: "{% if enforce_config==true %}always{% else %}on_create{% endif %}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
update_password: "{{ ‘always’ if (`enforce_config` == true) else ‘on_create’ }}"
```

Or

```
update_password: "{{ (`enforce_config` == true) | ternary(‘always’, ‘on_create’) }}"
```